# Problema lógico ao atribuir valor utilizando JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Como explicado no paragrafo abaixo o objetivo é criar um jogo de apostas, até ai tudo bem, a aposta Impar funciona perfeitamente somando o valor apostado ao total de pontos porém o mesmo não acontece com a aposta Par ela simplesmente não atribui nada (e a comparação lógica é a mesma e até mesmo retornando a mensagem do escopo).

```js
var quantidadeApostada;
    var totalDePontos;
    var sorteio;
    
    function validarJogada() {
        if (document.formulario.parOuImpar[0].checked == false && document.formulario.parOuImpar[1].checked == false) {
            alert("Por favor escolha entre par ou impar !");
            return false;
        }
    
        quantidadeApostada = parseInt(document.getElementById("valor").value);
        totalDePontos = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalDePontos").innerHTML);
    
        if(quantidadeApostada < 0 || quantidadeApostada > 30){
            alert("Por favor informe uma aposta valida, entre 1 a 30 !!");
            return false;
        }
    
        if(quantidadeApostada > totalDePontos){
            alert("Sua aposta esta maior que seu total de pontos !!!");
            return false;
        }
    
         sorteio = Math.floor(Math.random()* 30 + 1);
    
        validarSorteio(sorteio, quantidadeApostada, totalDePontos);
    }
    
    function  validarSorteio() {
    
        if (document.querySelector('input[name = parOuImpar]:checked').value === "Par" && sorteio%2 === 0){
            alert("O número sorteado foi : " +sorteio+" sendo ele um número PAR");
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos + parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
            document.getElementById('pontos').value = totalDePontos;
            novaQuantidadeDePontos();
        }
    
        if (document.querySelector('input[name = parOuImpar]:checked').value === "Impar" && sorteio%2 === 1){
            alert("O número sorteado foi : " +sorteio+" sendo ele um número IMPAR");
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos + parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
            document.getElementById('pontos').value = totalDePontos;
            novaQuantidadeDePontos();
        } else{
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos - parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
            document.getElementById('pontos').value = totalDePontos;
            novaQuantidadeDePontos();
        }
    }
    
    function  novaQuantidadeDePontos() {
        var pontosExibir = document.getElementById('pontos').value;
    
        document.getElementById("totalDePontos").innerText = pontosExibir;
    }
    
    
    novaQuantidadeDePontos();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="pt-br"> 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>exercicio-5</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/folhaDeEstilo.css"> 
</head> 
<body>
  <p id="semAlinhamento">
    Vamos criar nosso primeiro jogo! O usuário começa o jogo com 100 pontos. Deve ser apresentado 2 radio buttons,
    com os valores par e impar, e um campo de texto valor da aposta. Após selecionar preencher todos os campos, o
    usuário deve clicar em um botão jogar, então o sistema deve sortear um número aleatório de 1 à 30, e verificar
    se este número é par ou impar. Caso o número seja de acordo com o que o usuário apostou, deve-se somar a
    quantidade de pontos apostados ao seus pontos globais, caso seja diferente deve-se subtrair este valor. <br>
    Não deve ser possível clicar no botão jogar: <br>
    Não deve ser aceito nada além de valores numéricos, maior que zero, no campo valor da aposta.
    O sistema deve apresentar ao usuário qual número foi sorteado e informa-lo se o número é par ou impar. <br>
    Não deve ser possível clicar no botão jogar
    Caso o usuário não possua ou tente apostar uma quantidade de pontos maior do que possui.
    Caso o usuário não informe em qual tipo de número quer apostar.
  </p>
  <form name="formulario">
    <fieldset id="campoFormulario">
      <p>Vamos brincar !!!</p>
      <p>Escolha uma opção entre Par ou Impar e então aposte uma quantidade de pontos!!</p>
      <p>Boa Sorte !!!</p>
      <h3 id="subTitulo">Seu número total de pontos é <span id="totalDePontos"></span></h3>
      <input type="hidden" value="100" id="pontos">
      <input type="radio" name="parOuImpar" value="Par" class="radios">Par
      <input type="radio" name="parOuImpar" value="Impar" class="radios">Impar <br>
      <label for="valor" id="valorDaAposta">Valor da aposta</label>
      <input type="number" id="valor" min="1" max="30"> <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="validarJogada()" id="botaoJogar"> Jogar</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara pelo que vi, na sua função `validarSorteio()` quando era par entrava normal no `if`, porém logo abaixo tinha outro `if` com um `else` que fazia o valor voltar ao anterior. Um if estava anulando o outro. Apenas adicionei um `else if`.

Espero que seja isso:

```js
var quantidadeApostada;
    var totalDePontos;
    var sorteio;
    
    function validarJogada() {
        if (document.formulario.parOuImpar[0].checked == false && document.formulario.parOuImpar[1].checked == false) {
            alert("Por favor escolha entre par ou impar !");
            return false;
        }
    
        quantidadeApostada = parseInt(document.getElementById("valor").value);
        totalDePontos = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalDePontos").innerHTML);
    
        if(quantidadeApostada < 0 || quantidadeApostada > 30){
            alert("Por favor informe uma aposta valida, entre 1 a 30 !!");
            return false;
        }
    
        if(quantidadeApostada > totalDePontos){
            alert("Sua aposta esta maior que seu total de pontos !!!");
            return false;
        }
    
         sorteio = Math.floor(Math.random()* 30 + 1);
    
        validarSorteio(sorteio, quantidadeApostada, totalDePontos);
    }
    
    function  validarSorteio() {
    
        if (document.querySelector('input[name = parOuImpar]:checked').value === "Par" && sorteio%2 === 0){
            alert("O número sorteado foi : " +sorteio+" sendo ele um número PAR");
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos + parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
            document.getElementById('pontos').value = totalDePontos;
            novaQuantidadeDePontos();
        }else if (document.querySelector('input[name = parOuImpar]:checked').value === "Impar" && sorteio%2 === 1){
            alert("O número sorteado foi : " +sorteio+" sendo ele um número IMPAR");
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos + parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
            document.getElementById('pontos').value = totalDePontos;
            novaQuantidadeDePontos();
        } else{
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos - parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
            document.getElementById('pontos').value = totalDePontos;
            novaQuantidadeDePontos();
        }
    }
    
    function  novaQuantidadeDePontos() {
        var pontosExibir = document.getElementById('pontos').value;
    
        document.getElementById("totalDePontos").innerText = pontosExibir;
    }
    
    
    novaQuantidadeDePontos();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="pt-br"> 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>exercicio-5</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/folhaDeEstilo.css"> 
</head> 
<body>
  <p id="semAlinhamento">
    Vamos criar nosso primeiro jogo! O usuário começa o jogo com 100 pontos. Deve ser apresentado 2 radio buttons,
    com os valores par e impar, e um campo de texto valor da aposta. Após selecionar preencher todos os campos, o
    usuário deve clicar em um botão jogar, então o sistema deve sortear um número aleatório de 1 à 30, e verificar
    se este número é par ou impar. Caso o número seja de acordo com o que o usuário apostou, deve-se somar a
    quantidade de pontos apostados ao seus pontos globais, caso seja diferente deve-se subtrair este valor. <br>
    Não deve ser possível clicar no botão jogar: <br>
    Não deve ser aceito nada além de valores numéricos, maior que zero, no campo valor da aposta.
    O sistema deve apresentar ao usuário qual número foi sorteado e informa-lo se o número é par ou impar. <br>
    Não deve ser possível clicar no botão jogar
    Caso o usuário não possua ou tente apostar uma quantidade de pontos maior do que possui.
    Caso o usuário não informe em qual tipo de número quer apostar.
  </p>
  <form name="formulario">
    <fieldset id="campoFormulario">
      <p>Vamos brincar !!!</p>
      <p>Escolha uma opção entre Par ou Impar e então aposte uma quantidade de pontos!!</p>
      <p>Boa Sorte !!!</p>
      <h3 id="subTitulo">Seu número total de pontos é <span id="totalDePontos"></span></h3>
      <input type="hidden" value="100" id="pontos">
      <input type="radio" name="parOuImpar" value="Par" class="radios">Par
      <input type="radio" name="parOuImpar" value="Impar" class="radios">Impar <br>
      <label for="valor" id="valorDaAposta">Valor da aposta</label>
      <input type="number" id="valor" min="1" max="30"> <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="validarJogada()" id="botaoJogar"> Jogar</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Explicando**

O primeiro if da função verifica se esta selecionada a opção par, se não estiver não acontece nada. Já o segundo if tem um else, então quando estava selecionada a opção par ele entrava no primeiro e quando ia pro segundo dava falso pois não era impar que estava selecionado e acabava executando o else, que era justamente o que subtraia voltando ao valor normal.

Consegue compreender? Entava sendo executado o primeiro if e depois o else do segundo if. Então era adicionado o valor da aposta e depois entrava no else que anulava ele.

Comment: Cara funcionou perfeitamente , mas você poderia me explicar como um if anulava o outro ?Por que assim uma condição é diferente do outro

Comment: Sem problemas.

Vou explicar na resposta acima. Só 1 minuto.

Comment: Tentei explicar ai, espero que compreenda. Valeu! :D

Comment: Cara muito obrigado . Valews

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplificar a comparação para um `if else` dessa forma:

No formulario altere os values para `0` e `1`

```
<input type="radio" name="parOuImpar" value="0" class="radios">Par
<input type="radio" name="parOuImpar" value="1" class="radios">Impar
```

No script compare o `value` do input selecionado com o modulo da variavel `sorteio`

```
var valInput = document.querySelector('input[name = parOuImpar]:checked').value;
var modSorteio = sorteio%2;

      if (valInput == modSorteio ){
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos + parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
      } else{
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos - parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
      }
      alert("O número sorteado foi : " +sorteio+" sendo ele um número "+msg);
      document.getElementById('pontos').value = totalDePontos;
      novaQuantidadeDePontos();
```

**Código total funcionando**

```js
var quantidadeApostada;
    var totalDePontos;
    var sorteio;
    var msg;
    
    function validarJogada() {
        if (document.formulario.parOuImpar[0].checked == false && document.formulario.parOuImpar[1].checked == false) {
            alert("Por favor escolha entre par ou impar !");
            return false;
        }
    
        quantidadeApostada = parseInt(document.getElementById("valor").value);
        totalDePontos = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalDePontos").innerHTML);
    
        if(quantidadeApostada < 0 || quantidadeApostada > 30){
            alert("Por favor informe uma aposta valida, entre 1 a 30 !!");
            return false;
        }
    
        if(quantidadeApostada > totalDePontos){
            alert("Sua aposta esta maior que seu total de pontos !!!");
            return false;
        }
    
         sorteio = Math.floor(Math.random()* 30 + 1);
    
        validarSorteio(sorteio, quantidadeApostada, totalDePontos);
    }
    
    function  validarSorteio() {

      if (sorteio%2===0){
        msg="Par";
      }else{
         msg="Impar";
      }
      
      var valInput = document.querySelector('input[name = parOuImpar]:checked').value;
      var modSorteio = sorteio%2;
      
      if (valInput == modSorteio ){
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos + parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
      } else{
            totalDePontos = totalDePontos - parseInt(quantidadeApostada);
      }
      alert("O número sorteado foi : " +sorteio+" sendo ele um número "+msg);
      document.getElementById('pontos').value = totalDePontos;
      novaQuantidadeDePontos();
   }
    
    function  novaQuantidadeDePontos() {
        var pontosExibir = document.getElementById('pontos').value;
    
        document.getElementById("totalDePontos").innerText = pontosExibir;
    }
    
    
    novaQuantidadeDePontos();
```

```html
        <form name="formulario">
            <fieldset id="campoFormulario">
                <p>Vamos brincar !!!</p>
                <p>Escolha uma opção entre Par ou Impar e então aposte uma quantidade de pontos!!</p>
                <p>Boa Sorte !!!</p>
                <h3 id="subTitulo">Seu número total de pontos é <span id="totalDePontos"></span></h3>
                <input type="hidden" value="100" id="pontos">
                <input type="radio" name="parOuImpar" value="0" class="radios">Par
                <input type="radio" name="parOuImpar" value="1" class="radios">Impar <br>
                 <label for="valor" id="valorDaAposta">Valor da aposta</label>
                <input type="number" id="valor" min="1" max="30"> <br>
                <button type="button" onclick="validarJogada()" id="botaoJogar">Jogar</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```